# Change content of one div while scrolling in another div

Tags: load, scroll, overflow

I have two div's, one of them with an image and another one with text (css overflow propriety). I'd like to know how I can change the image in the first div while I am scrolling in the second one. For example, when I scroll the text, the image would change after the first paragraph, and again after the second paragraph. I think you understand. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you use `.offset` to get the position of each text div and change the image depending on how far the user has scrolled. [Here is an example of the concept](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/dyz6X/)

The basic concept:

```js
$('.container').scroll(function () {
    var bottom_of_container = $('.container').scrollTop() + $('.container').height();
    $('.content').each(function (i) {
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() + 500;
        if (bottom_of_container > bottom_of_object) {
            if ($('.content').eq(0).html() == $(this).html()) {
                $('.image').src = 'http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff';
                    $('.image').css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            if ($('.content').eq(1).html() == $(this).html()) {
                $('.image').src = 'http://dummyimage.com/750x486/000/AAA.png&text=2';
                $('.image').css('background-color', 'blue');
            }
            if ($('.content').eq(2).html() == $(this).html()) {
                $('.image').src = 'http://dummyimage.com/750x486/000/AAA.png&text=3';
                $('.image').css('background-color', 'black');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Let me know if I can do anything to help

Comment: Thanks for being so nice with me. I still don't get how the "$('.image').src" can work. Only "$('.image').css" works. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/Dt6UK/

Comment: `.src` is a javascript function that sets changes the `src` of a `<img>` tag to the specified value, thus changing the image. I was just changing the background color instead of the src to start because images weren't showing up in my jsfiddle for some reason. From the original question you wanted to change the image when the paragraph is reached, so just use the `$('.image').src` lines and replace the URL with the image you want it to change to

Comment: I've tried only add '$('.image').src' on the code, but I haven't sucess yet. should I link for a web page? When I tried, I only put images in a folder.

Comment: Hi again Zeaklous, I still don't get to make the ".src" works. =/ Do you have another ideia? Maybe I could set a image with a css property.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't put this in the first place: For images the best practice would be to use `$('.image').css('background-image', 'url(URLGOESHERE.gif)');`. You also have do put some default CSS for it, namely `background-size:cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;`, depending on how you want them to look. [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/dyz6X/17/)