# Change div background color while scrolling in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 div's: `.numbers` and `.text`

The `.text` div has a height of 120px and `overflow-y: scroll`.

I would like to change the background in the `.numbers` div while scrolling in `.text`

I have tried using what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517711/change-content-of-one-div-while-scrolling-in-another-div) question without results.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/se1r3cv4/) what I tried

Any hints?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: was this useful for u ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure javascript:

```
//Here you get the elements from the HTML
const textEl = document.querySelector('.text')
const numberEl = document.querySelector('.numbers')

//Here you add an event listener that change the .numbers color
textEl.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
numberEl.style.backgroundColor = "red"
//Here you reset the color 
//You can increase the number below if you do not want the color to reset immediately)
setTimeout(() => numberEl.style.backgroundColor = "transparent", 100)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used offsetTop to change the background color of div as per the index of Paragraph tag

#### This will work

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var margin_top_bottom = 40;
var another_div = document.getElementsByClassName('another_div')[0];
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

var color = ["#FFCD00", "#006CFF", "#A600FF", "#8988FF"];
content.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrolled = content.scrollTop;


  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (scrolled >= p[i].offsetTop - margin_top_bottom) {
      another_div.style.backgroundColor = color[i % color.length];
    }
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.content {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.another_div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.another_div h1 {
  font-size: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="another_div">
  <h1>COLOR CHANGE ON SCROLL</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks! I have a question: what if the Paragraphs are dynamic? I mean what if they are more than 4? does this also works in case I have 5 paragraphs? I mean without manually change color for each paragraph

Comment: @Febula you can create an array  having certain color stored and the moment last index of color appears it would revert back to initial index of array and form a loop.You could see in my code the way i assigned color to 'another_div'.for eg if there are 8 p elements and 4 color elements so when 5th p element appears color index would change to 0 again